# For a message length n, what is the cost of pgp(n), sign(n) and encrypt(n)?

Tags: algorithm, security, time-complexity

By message, I mean any string of data, utf-8 preferably.

By cost/time, I mean algorithm complexity (the number of operations).

By "the cost of pgp", I mean the time it takes to transform a string of data length n, into a string of data for pgp communication (no middle-man can see the message, and we know the origin).

By "the cost of sign", I mean the time it takes to sign a string of data, into a signature to attach (a middle-man can see the message, but we know the origin).

By "the cost of encrypt", I mean the time it takes to encrypt a string of data, into encrypted data (a middle man can't see the message, but we can't provably know the origin).

We assume the keys have been generated and it represents the typical time in an established system

Clearly said, I'd like to compare the trade-offs of these security measures

Comment: The "time it takes" really depends on the hardware you use, but It will be O(n).

Comment: I have been downvoted, yet according to this, signing is O(log(n)), so maybe it's not as simple as it seems. https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/crypto/broadcast.html

I know O(log(n)) is O(n), but it isn't practically relevant (but thanks for the answer). I wished I could have had more details and linear factors and I think it would have been an interesting question. Anyway, O(n) is good enough to know for my case, thanks again

Comment: @Pierre: Neither of the mentions of "O(log n)" on that page refer to the time needed to *compute* sign(n).

Comment: You may be right about it, thanks, I still think that for a program which encodes all of its communicating data, it is useful to know whether something is 2n or n. It's hard to find all the complexity data about this stuff, though it matters and will probably matter more and more.

Comment: And nevermind, I haven't been downvoted (but I admit I should have been clearer). I found elsewhere that PGP compresses data before encrypting it, so it seems to be around 2n minimum, there. Compressing all data sounds like quite a overhead. But apparently, raw encryption has security problems with uncompressed data, so suffers the same, if we want to transmit it. Finally, I think it's best and easier to just run statistics on data sets, rather than trying to theorize.